# Ошибка POST запроса с типом содержимого multipart/form-data

Tags: java, android, post, httpurlconnection

Возникла проблема по передаче изображения на сервер. Данный код написан для `Android` и работает только с версией `4.1` и ниже. При использовании в других версиях ловит `ProtocolException`.
Разрешение на доступ к файлам есть.

```
public class FilesUploadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog WaitingDialog;
    private String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private String twoHyphens = "--";
    private String boundary =  "Asrf456BGe4h";

    // Переменные для считывания файла в оперативную память
    private int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    private byte[] buffer;
    private int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    private String filePath, fullSize;

    // Адрес метода api для загрузки файла на сервер
    public static final String API_FILES_UPLOADING_PATH = "адрес пути отправки запроса";

    // Ключ, под которым файл передается на сервер
    public static final String FORM_FILE_NAME = "file";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        WaitingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Отправка данных",
                "Отправляем изображение... \n Это может занять продолжительное время", true);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    public FilesUploadingTask(String filePath, String fullSize) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.fullSize = fullSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Результат выполнения запроса, полученный от сервера
        String result = "null";

        try {
            // Создание ссылки для отправки файла
            URL uploadUrl = new URL(API_FILES_UPLOADING_PATH);

            // Создание соединения для отправки файла
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uploadUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.spamu.net");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + fullSize);

            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            // Начало контента
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(sName + lineEnd);

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"contact\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(sPhone + lineEnd);

            // Формирование multipart контента
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            // Заголовок элемента формы
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                    FORM_FILE_NAME + "\"; filename=\"" + filePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
            // Тип данных элемента формы
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd);
            // Конец заголовка
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // Поток для считывания файла в оперативную память
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Считывание файла в оперативную память и запись его в соединение
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // Конец элемента формы
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            if(serverResponseCode == 200) {
                result = readStream(conn.getInputStream());
            } else {
                result = readStream(conn.getErrorStream());
            }
            //Log.d("classInJson", "result > " + result);
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("classInJson", "Ошибка соединения с сервером > " + result);
            WaitingDialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "MailformedURLe";
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("classInJson", "Несовпадение протоколов передачи данных > " + result);
            WaitingDialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Protocole";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("classInJson", "Файл не найден > " + result);
            WaitingDialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "NoFilee";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("classInJson", "Ошибка передачи данных > " + result);
            WaitingDialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "IOe";
        }
    }

    public String readStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

        switch (result) {
            case"MailformedURLe":
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ошибка соединения с сервером", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case "Protocole":
                Toast.makeText(context, "Несовпадение протоколов передачи данных", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case "NoFilee":
                Toast.makeText(context, "Файл для передачи не найден", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case "IOe":
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ошибка передачи", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject resultdata = dataJsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WaitingDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Советую познакомиться с okhttp и retrofit. вам хватит первой либы для этой задачи

Comment: Рассматривал такой вариант, но пока думаю, то лучше исправить готовый вариант, чем писать все заново.

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-multipart-request готовый пример "как отправить файл за 22 строки кода"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил, опишу, может поможет кому.

Ошибка заключается в несоответствии заданного размера памяти в строчке (`conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + fullSize`)) и используемого при передаче.

Решается заменой строк вида:

`outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);`

На:

`outputStream.write(lineEnd.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Кодировка в конце соответствует кодировке, с которой работает сервер.

На крайний случай можно удалить и саму строку, где указывается Content-Length.